# Regular expression not working?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Let's just jump right in:

JS

```js
function detailCheck() {
  var phNoLength = document.getElementById('phNo').value.length;  //get value for phone number from form for checking
  var cardNoLength = document.getElementById('cardNo').value.length; //get value for card number length for checking 
  var postCodeLength = document.getElementById("postCode").value.length //get value for post code length
  var a = /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/; 
  var b = /^[A-Za-z]+$/; 
//if form is not got all inputs filled 
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   details = document.getElementById("myForm")[i].value;
   if (details === "") {
     var i = ("Please enter ALL your details."); 
     document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i;
    return;
    }
}
//check if names have numbers in them
if(b.test(document.getElementById("fName").value)){                                                                     
 if(b.test(document.getElementById("lName").value)){
 //if names too short
  if(fName < 3) {i = "Please enter a longer first name."; document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}
   if(lName < 3) {i = "Please enter a longer last name."; document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}
 //if phone number not number
    if(a.test(document.getElementById("phNo").value)){
 //if phone number too short  
     if(phNoLength != 7) {var i ="Please use a phone number with 7 digits";document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}
 //if CC is not a number
      if(a.test(document.getElementById("cardNo").value)){
 //if CC is too short
       if(cardNoLength != 4) {var i ="Please use a card number with 4 digits";document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}
 //if post code is not a number
        if(a.test(document.getElementById("postCode").value)){
         if(postCodeLength != 4) {var i ="Please use a card number with 4 digits";document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}


     } else {var i ="Please only use numbers in your post code."; document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}

    } else {var i ="Please only use numbers in your credit card."; document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}

   } else {var i ="Please only use numbers in your Phone number."; document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}
   
  } else {var i = "Please don't use numbers in your last name."; document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}
  
 } else {var i = "Please don't use numbers in your first name."; document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i; return;}
toggleContent();
}
```

```html
 <form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
    First name: <br> <input class="formInput" type="text" id="fName" name="fName"><br>
    Last name: <br> <input class="formInput" type="text" id="lName" name="lName"><br>
    Phone Number: <br> <input class="formInput" type="number" id="phNo" name="phNo" maxlength="7"><br>
    Credit Card Number: <br> <input class="formInput" type="password" id="cardNo" name="cardNo" maxlength="4"><br>
    Address: <br> <input class="formInput" type="text" id="address" name="address"><br>
    Post code: <br> <input class="formInput" type="number" id="postCode" name="postCode" maxlength="4"><br>
   </form>
```

I can pass an input into phone number like -234567 and have it go through despite `var a = /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/;` . if I add 123456+ for example, nothing happens.

Comment: The string -234567 matches the pattern you have for `a`, so why wouldn't it go through? What do you expect to happen? What behavior are you seeing that is different from what you want to see?

Comment: What we need is for you to clearly and completely state what combination of characters (i.e. numbers) that you desire to match, or not match the desired [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Please use examples.

Comment: Your best bet for a solution is to Google something like: [javascript regular expression tester](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=javascript+regular+expression+tester). Make sure you pick one that *explicitly* states that it is using JavaScript regular expressions (there are multiple types).  Then use the site you picked to try various regular expressions to match what you desire.

Comment: @Makyen I just wrote a comment doing just that. Sorry for don't doing this before, I thought it was something other than my RegExp!

Comment: You probably want something like `/^(\(?\d{3}[)-]?)?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/` which should match a couple/few different formats of US phone numbers.

Comment: I don't need to go that far for this program, just 0 to 9 and not - + e will do fine :) Other than that, how does my overall code look?

Comment: @Draxy, If you want a review of functioning code, then [codereview.se] is a good place to ask for it.  Generally: Don't use single character variable names. Sometimes it is OK to do so in short, tight loops for the loop index, but otherwise do so only rarely, or specific circumstances. Definitely not multiple ones throughout your code. In `for` loop you re-define `i` don't do that. Multiple times you define a variable `i` just to use it only once in the next expression. No need for that. Please format your `if` blocks 1 statement to a line. Keep comments lined up with the lines they are about.

Comment: Your code seems to do what it claims. So there is something going on other than what you are telling  us.

Comment: @Draxy, I have reverted your question to the original version. You can find the text of the prior version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/88a04149-1137-47d2-a6db-b28b1392d271/view-source). Completely changing what the question is about is not something that should be done. You can revise the question to make it more clear as to what you are asking about (always feel free to do so). But, changing the text to ask a *different* question is not to be done. If you have a new question then ask it as a new question. Feel free to use a link to this question to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
var a = /^[-+]?[0-9]+\+$/;
```

```js
var a = /^[-+]?[0-9]+\+$/;
console.log("123456+".match(a))
```

Comment: What does this change / accomplish?

Comment: Strange, I'm not sure what that did, but it no longer passes - witch is good. + returns "Please only use numbers in your Phone number." witch is weird. e can also be put in a number input, this returns "Please enter ALL your details",  witch means for sone weird reason, it dose not count the form as "filled". Any Ideas?

Comment: @Draxy, He added `\+` just before the `$`. This forces the last character to be a `+`, which is probably not what you desire.

Comment: Just within 0 and 9 and NOT -+e does anyone know the code for this? Could be my regular expression is wrong.

Comment: This may or may not work, but should not be necessary. What is wrong with the OP's original logic?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as to what you are really wanting. Assuming that you want to match US phone numbers with a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), the following will mach multiple styles of representing a 10 or 7 digit US phone number:

```
var phoneNumberRegExp = /^(?:\(?([2-9]\d{2})[)-]? ?)?([2-9]\d{2})-?(\d{4})$/;
```

This should match:

```
2134567
213-4567
213-456-7890
(213)456-7890
(213) 456-7890
```

Note: `0` and `1` are not valid first digits for either an area code or a prefix (the first 3 numbers of a 7 digit phone number).

The first [capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) will be the area code. The second is the prefix (exchange). The third is the subscriber number.

However, a regular expression is really not sufficient for validating a phone number.  You are much better off using a specialized library like [Google's libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber).

Comment: His question seems very clear to me. He wants to exclude any entry that contains any of the characters in his character set.

Comment: By the way, where did you get the idea this was about phone numbers? It seems to be about postal codes.

Comment: @torazaburo, I wrote an answer to the [original question, which was about phone numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39188264/1).  The OP massively revised his question 2 hours ago.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.

Comment: @torazaburo, No problem. It was an unusual situation. I would not expect anyone to go searching through the question history to see if was changed so dramatically. I appreciate your leaving a note to ask about it. That was the best thing to do.  I certainly desire to know if an answer of mine was is that far off base.